# Java 1.7 issue, Enter key pressed work differently

Tags: java, java-7

I have following code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TesttxtF {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextField txt1 = new TextField();
        TextField txt2 = new TextField();

        DefaultFocusManager manager = new DefaultFocusManager() {
            @Override
            public void processKeyEvent(Component focusedComponent, KeyEvent e) {
                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
                    if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
                        super.focusNextComponent(focusedComponent);
                    else
                        super.processKeyEvent(focusedComponent, e);
                    break;

                default:
                    super.processKeyEvent(focusedComponent, e);
                    break;
                }

            }
        };
        FocusManager.setCurrentManager(manager);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(txt1);
        panel.add(txt2);

        txt1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Key keyTyped");
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Key keyReleased");
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Key Pressed");
            }
        });

        txt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Action performed");
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel, null);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

When run with

jdk1.6.0_18 -> output as following when pressing enter key

```
Key Pressed
Key keyTyped
Action performed
```

jdk1.7.0_12 -> output as following when pressing enter key

```
Key Pressed
```

What is wrong with java 7 then ?

when i typed any number and clear the console. Then press the Enter key focus changed to next component but actionperformed never fired in java 7. How i can fix it ? i had checked with java 7 update 25 also. i got same result. Can anybody help ?

Comment: You should put the contents of your comment in the question itself

Comment: Wrap the entire code in main(String[]) in a Runnable and pass that to SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable) and try again.

Comment: No it's not working @Jukka. Any other suggestion ?